# rebol: How to create rule to parse braces?

Tags: rebol

I really don't master Parse rule yet :)

How do I parse this ?

```
to-parse: [entity Person {
    String name
    String lastName
    Address home
    Address business
}]
```

This doesn't work:

```
entity-rule: ['entity word! #"{" to end]
>> parse to-parse entity-rule
== false
>>
```

Answer (score 5):

The third element in your **to-parse** block is not the char **{**. It's a **string** -- REBOL strings can be delineated **"..."** or **{...}**

```
type? to-parse/3
== string!
to-parse/3
{
   String name
   String lastName
   Address home
   Address business
}
```

To parse the block successfully, you need to be looking for a string:

```
entity-rule: ['entity word! string! to end]
parse to-parse entity-rule
== true
```

Answer (score 5):

```
to-parse: [entity Person {
    String name
    String lastName
    Address home
    Address business
}]

person-rule: [  
    thru "String " copy name to newline (append names name) thru newline |
    thru "Address " copy address to newline (append addresses address) thru newline |
    skip end
]

parse to-parse [ 
    'entity 'person 
    set details string! (
        names: copy [] addresses: copy []
        parse details [ some person-rule ]
    )
]
```

will collect the names into the block names, and addresses into the block addresses.
This answer doesn't work in Rebol3 though.  Not sure why not.

Comment: I tested your code in R3, and actually, it works. However, the **skip end** part looks unusual, didn't you mean **to end** or **break**?

Comment: Or, maybe you meant **end skip**?

Comment: Actually, I guess that the **skip end** part is just superfluous.